# Severe jQuery lag on Firefox & Chrome, not IE though

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox, lag

As stated in the title, this one-page site with minimal jQuery is suffering from crazy lag on Chrome and Firefox, but **not** on IE10. I do realize MS stepped up their game with 10, but for the sweet lord's sake, what is the deal?

I've read that sometimes Chrome is laggy with div hide()s and show()s, but I'm using fadeIn() and fadeOut(), and it seems like there's something I'm missing.

I've created a JSFiddle for it in case I've somehow done something horrifically wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/g2avityhitz/ZdqEd/1/

```
(function($){
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $("#picbox .tiny img").click( function () {
            $("#picbox .tiny img").removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
            $("#picbox .main").css({
                'background-image'  : 'url(' + imgSrc + ')'
            });
            $("#picbox .main a").attr('href',imgSrc);
        });

        $("#picbox .main a").click( function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            imgSrc = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#lightbox .frame img").remove();
            $("#lightbox .frame").append('<img src="' + imgSrc + '" />');
            $("#lightbox").fadeIn(500, function () {
                $('#lightbox .frame .close').click( function () {
                    $("#lightbox").fadeOut(200);
                });
            });
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Please and thank you.

**Edit:** Great responses, but just to point out again - No lag in **IE**, only in Chrome and Firefox. What could be behind this?

Comment: Even when I delete all your JavaScript, there is very serious lag when looking at the top images. One of your plugins isn't playing nice.

Comment: First of all, you need to cache those jQuery objects. You are creating them over and over unnecessarily.

Comment: Dave - All I'm using is jQuery-latest. Scott - I'm still sort of a JS noob, so I don't follow your caching suggestion.

Comment: I'll post an answer so you can see the caching part.

Answer (score 2):

***[Here is an example of caching that would optimize what you have.](http://jsfiddle.net/ZdqEd/9/)***

Will it solve everything? Not sure, but it will definitely help things.

**Cached code:**

```js
var $images = $("#picbox .tiny img"),
    $main = $("#picbox .main"),
    $mainLinks = $main.find("a"),
    $lightbox = $("#lightbox"),
    $frame = $lightbox.find(".frame"),
    $frameImages = $frame.find("img");

    $images.on("click", function () 
    {
        var $this = $(this);

        $images.removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');
        imgSrc = $this.attr('src');
        $main.css({ 'background-image': 'url(' + imgSrc + ')' });
        $mainLinks.attr('href', imgSrc);
    });

    $mainLinks.on("click", function (e) 
    {   
        e.preventDefault();

        imgSrc = $(this).attr('href');
        $frameImages.remove();
        $frame.append('<img src="' + imgSrc + '" />');
        $lightbox.fadeIn(500, function () 
        {
            $frame.find(".close").on("click", function () 
            {
                $lightbox.fadeOut(200);
            });     
        });
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Though not a fix for the issue (obviously), this is awesome. Thanks man, super helpful and much cleaner.